How to club different input parameters under one input paramer
I created multiple indicators with their specific input parameters. When I combine both I have to work on multiple input parameters on off to disable one indicator complete.
I want a single input parameter which will hold all other code under it and I can switch off or switch on at highest level
I tried input.bull but unable to get all code under it

Please share the code you have tried and specific output; see [mcve] for info on what data we need to see in your question, as text in order to better help you.
